# Jquery: Getting the id of an html element: why one solution works and the other don't

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am referencing one element on an index page hidden initially and then showed with jquery on an index.html page. Can't explain why the first ones doesn't work, even if it should, but the last one does. I am getting the id of a pressed button "id='edit1'...2...3..etc" Thank you!

```
//why this doesn't work and the next one does???
/*$('.edit-btn').click(function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 console.log("btn1:", id);
 });

$('.edit-btn').on('click', function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 console.log("btn1:", id);
 });
 */

var id;
$("body").on("click",".edit-btn",function(){
id = (this.id).replace("edit","");
```

UPDATE:

The containers are hidden and shown using this function:

```
function hideWindowsAndShowOneWindow(sWindowId) {
$('.wdw').hide(); //fadeout 500
$('#' + sWindowId).show(); // fade in 500
}
```

So the div container, I am trying to reference by id was hidden after the page was loaded or maybe before the page is loaded. My guess is after the page is loaded...

The HTML:

```
<div class="wdw" id="wdw-events">

<h4>Events text</h4></br>
   <div id="content"></div>
    <h4>Edit Events</h4></br>
    <div>

</div>
```

It is added/injected after the page was loaded with this js script, but still what has the last method special, just referencing through the document down to the id attribute of the button:

```
  finalEventsLS.forEach(function (item) {
    var date = item.date.day + "/" +item.date.month + "/" + item.date.year;
    $('#content').append("<ul><li>" +
      "Event nr.: " + item.id + "   " +
      "Name: " + item.name + "   " +
      "Topic: "+ item.topic + "   " +
      "Speaker: "+ item.speaker + "   " +
      "Date: " + date + "&emsp;" +
      "</li><button class='edit-btn' id='edit" + item.id + "'>Edit</button>
   </ul>");

  })
```

Comment: Is the button hidden (with CSS styles) or injected into the body after the document is loaded?

Comment: initially was hidden but then shown and press on it, it should fire the event, not hidden in css because I can see the buttons. Not injected just hidden initially...

Comment: The difference is event delegation. See http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: Note that you can get the ID by just using `this.id`.

Comment: I know but this was other problem, I was referencing the object direct and couldn't access it since it was added later in the DOM, but only through the document I could reference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell, since you've only shared your jQuery. Update with your HTML please.

If you are referencing an element which was added to the DOM after the initial page load, [`.click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) will not work, because it only looks for elements initially loaded into the DOM. Instead, you would use the [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, which looks for elements added to the DOM both before and after initial load.

**UPDATE:**

I should have looked closer. The second snippet of code that didn't work, but used the .on method, most likely didn't work because you are still trying to access the `.edit-btn` element, which at this point I'm assuming was added after page load. The code snippet that does work, is accessing the `body` element first. I will try to find and update with a better explanation, but the `.on` method still needs to find a element that existed in the DOM initially. From there, it can climb down the tree to find `.edit-btn` element.

Comment: the on method doesn't work either, the one in the commented snippet, but the second one does, it was loaded in the dom but hidden at the beginning with jquery. The html contains just some div containers shown or hidden depending on the nav menu links pressed

Comment: So every element was pre-loaded into the DOM?

Comment: But a div container is not loaded in the DOM if is hidden in the beginning? I thought it is still loaded as hidden and you can reference it as you please, by class or id.

Comment: I see you are hiding an element with class="wdw". Is this the same element as the element with class="edit-btn"?

Also, if you add your HTML, it can help me see the relations between elements.